# ssas tabular project property not show query mode

Tags: deployment, ssas, tabular

can anyone help this?
the SSAS project property not showing query mode?
have i messed with anything?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the .bim file in Solution Explorer and looking at the Properties pane. I assume this is the [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/enable-directquery-mode-in-ssdt?) you meant:

[image: DirectQuery Mode]

Comment: no, what i mean is under deployment options, there shall be query mode. no sure whether i create the project from right tool and or configuration.

Comment: also the version is unknown, and there is no impersonal settings as well. not sure whether it is install problem or i mess around anything myself.  can anyone help this? xnks

Comment: You are looking at circa 2012 documentation if you expect those settings. On the properties of the .bim file you should see compatibility level 1200 or above. Those old settings only applied to 1100 or 1103 compatibility level (SQL 2014 or below).

Comment: For impersonation check the data source properties. Look in Tabular Model Explorer pane. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/impersonation-ssas-tabular

Comment: What version of SSAS is on your server?

Comment: vs 2015 for SSAS project, check my further specification above.

Comment: @luke VS2015 is the dev tool version. What I want to know is the version of SSAS on the server you are deploying to. You need to match the compatibility level of the project up with the version of the server before you get too far.

Comment: Connect in SSMS to Analysis Services on the server and tell me the version number you see in the top server node

Comment: the analysis service version is 2017.140.249.3.

Comment: @luke got it. So that’s SSAS 2017. Just make sure your .bim file is compatibility level 1400 and you are good

Comment: If this answer resolves the question then be sure to hit the green checkmark icon!

Answer (score 0):

i am using Visual Studio  2015, and i expect the property page would like this as the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgM8H.png)attachment. 
not sure whether the tool install correctly or anything wrong else. 
cheers